# Sharepoint list 302 response from fetch API call to get list attachments

Tags: reactjs, fetch, sharepoint-online

I'm making a fetch call using the below api call to get attachments from a sharepoint online list.  For some reason when I've previously logged into sharepoint online, the API call works, but if I open a guest window in Chrome I receive a 302 response for the call and the images do not display.  None of the other API calls to sharepoint behave this way as I authenticate when logging into the application.

```
fetchListAttachments(personsStateArray: any[], index: number) {

    const dataUrl =
        `/api/spdata/GetListAttachments('${this.listName
            }')/items?$select=AttachmentFiles&$expand=AttachmentFiles`;

        fetch(dataUrl, { credentials: "include", headers: { accept: "application/json" } })
            .then(response => response.json());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to guest window not storing the Cookie that has Authenticated you. Also I imagine some, if not all SP Lists have to be requested via HTTPS. That aside you're code looks fine but it would be good for us to see how you present your JSON output i.e. show us the client code (`Render(),divs, <img/> etc`). I would do one more thing to determine if it's really a presentation issue or Response issue by that I mean try to load a List that's not images first and see. If they get returned then anything should and your issue is the UI layer not Response. I have code that Returns List fine in a similar `Fetch()` but obviously you can't just push the response.json() to client. Hope this helps.